# SuSE ImageWriter doesn't see my USB memory stick, though Windows does?

Tags: linux, usb, opensuse

I've just built a new server, on which I plan to install OpenSuSE Linux.  To avoid installing items that would only ever be used once, I've built the machine with no optical drives, and planned to install SuSE off a memory stick as detailed here: http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Create_a_Live_USB_stick_using_Windows

I bought a 32GB Kingston pen drive for the purpose (and general use afterwards), however while both my ageing Windows XP box at work, and my almost new Windows 7 PC at home, can see the memory stick fine in My Computer, SuSE Image Writer shows nothing in the drop-down box where the memory stick should show up - I've tried it on both computers, and on Win 7 both running it as my normal user and as Administrator.

The page has options for what to do if errors occur, but nothing about what to do if no stick shows up at all.

Anyone got any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: On SuSE, what is the output of sudo lshw -C disk

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I'm trying to create a bootable SuSE memory stick to install SuSE on the new server - the systems I'm creating the stick on run Windows.  The problem is that SuSE ImageWriter for Windows doesn't see the memory stick (or indeed any drives at all) as targets for the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be to forget ImageWriter and to instead use ImageUSB from http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html to write the memory stick.

Doing this I was able to boot correctly into the installation screens.

Answer (score 0):

Many people use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for such tasks, you may be luckier with this program.

Comment: I was following those instructions, I linked to them in my original post.  The three suggestions are what to do if you get a Windows error, no-where does it say anything about what to do if the program simply does not see any drives.

I'll have a look at Unetbootin, ta!

Comment: Unetbootin appears to have written the stick correctly, I'll have to go back to the datacentre and try it in the server to see if it works, if so, will mark your answer as correct.  Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, and here I am adding senseless words just to fullfill the minimum length requirement

Comment: Alas, wile Unetbootin did make the stick bootable, it doesn't seem to process the SuSE ISO properly as when the boot screen comes up the only option is "Default" and it just keeps going round and round the "Booting selected option in 10 seconds" thing and doesn't actually boot, even if selected manually.  openSuSE do say that other bootloaders won't work with their ISO, which would be fine if their own writer actually did.  :(